# Python loop to check each items in a list against other element

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops

I have been trying several loops but can't seem to achieve what I want. Here is what I have and what I am missing:

```
#Gets a list of all MAC addresses 
MACList = fetchMAC.MAC
i = 0
while i<len(MACList):
    #Gets data associated to MAC
    hostLogin(user, password, MACList[i])
    #After above function is executed, below variables will change values for each MAC, it adds second MAC to SecondMAC
    # It can not see ip associated to SecondMac so it puts "NA" under IPAddr2 as placeholder
    print "Data: ", MACList[i], SecondMAC, IPAddr1,IPAddr2, Host, Loc
    #Add all this data in a database
    MacDB.updateDB(MACList[i], SecondMAC, IPAddr,IPAddr2, Host, Loc)
    i +=1
    # I am stuck here
    # so after adding very first MAC, the loop starts over with i = 1
    # It goes thru hostlogin() function as usual and gets all data for second MAC. 
    # But before adding its own row in DB by calling updateDB(), I would like to check if this MAC is already exists. Three ways I believe we can check:
    # 1 - Compare new MAC is in SecondMAC variable of PREVIOUS MAC loop
    # 2 - Opposite of 1.  Check if previous MAC is in SecondMAC variable of THIS loop.
    # 3 - Query DB and see if it already exists under SecondMAC column of BD.
    # if second MAC in MACList is already in DB as SecondMAC
    # then run it though below func and if not, add it normally and move on to next MAC

    MacDB.editDB(MACList[i], SecondMAC, IPAddr)

    # Above func edits the row where MAC was stored and Sets the value of IPAddr2 for that SecondMAC.
```

Unfortunately, when I get data with hostLogin function, it can see MAC addresses but can only see ip address associated to that host and not IP associated to second MAC on same host.  This is the main reason I have to compare and make sure I am not adding a new entry of a MAC/IP that is part of a host with 2 NICS.

It will keep doing same for next MACs until none left.  This list should be fairly small so I am not worried too much about efficiency.

Any help will be awesome.

Comment: Does this say hostLogin alters global variables?

Comment: Yes, every time it runs, it alters global variables with new host data